# Return choices in model

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    types_choices = (
        (1, 'Sport'),
        (2, 'Turbo'),
        (3, 'Turbo++'),
    )   
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    d_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=types_choices, max_length=1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s, %s" % (self.car.name, types_choices[self.d_type][1])
```

In admin interface there is a error: `global name 'types_choices' is not defined`. I think it about my return. How to fix it? I need car name and 'sport'(or turbo, etc.) in one string in admin interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot the self.

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    types_choices = (
        (1, 'Sport'),
        (2, 'Turbo'),
        (3, 'Turbo++'),
    )   
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    d_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=types_choices, max_length=1)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s, %s" % (self.car.name, self.types_choices[self.d_type][1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `self.get_d_type_display()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self.types_choices`. This is because `types_choices` is a property on your 
`Detail` class.

Django docs have a good pattern on how to use choices: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

You can also use `self.get_d_type_display()` to get the verbose name of the choice field.